# Cake PHP 0.2.9 - Constructor issue

Tags: cakephp, constructor

I am working on the old Cakephp version 0.2.9

I tried to write a constructor

`function __construct`  and
`function __construct()` and with the same class name

But all getting error like **Fatal error: Call to a member function init() on a non-object in ..**

Comment: 0.2.9 is approaching a decade old - you should consider upgrading =).

Answer (score 2):

### When overriding a method call the parent

There are no details in the question but it's probable the new constructor that's been defined does not call the parent

i.e.

```
class Parent {

    protected $_name = '';

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    public function greet() {
        if (!$this->_name) {
            throw new Exception("I got no name");
        }
        return sprintf('Hi, I\'m %s', $this->_name);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public function __construct() {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

There are *two* errors in the above code example

1. Unintentionally not calling the parent class
2. Changing the method signature

The consequence of the first error is that this works:

```
$Parent = new Parent('Bob');
echo $Parent->greet();
```

Whereas this would throw an exception:

```
$Child = new Child('Boblini');
echo $Parent->greet();
```

Fixing the first problem alone will still cause an exception to be thrown, as the child constructor does not have the same arguments as the parent method, so it cannot pass the missing argument to the parent method.

### Summary

- Always call the overridden method (unless there's a specific reason not to)
- Ensure the method signature is the same as the overridden method

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I am not asking about the concept of costructor.But in cake php for a controller  for example                                                                class ShippingsController extends AppController  
{  
     function __construct()
    {
      //$this->set('pending_queue',$this->Shipping->numPendingQueue($this->Session->read('Shipper.id')));
    }                                                                      Getting error for this

Comment: 1) Doesn't look like you read the the answer (?) as the code example demonstrates _both_ problems mentioned 2) you shouldn't be doing that in the constructor 3) that should be in the question =) - along with the parent method's signature.